# android marker remove() method not working

Tags: android, google-maps-markers

I use List to store marker to add to gmap and remove component it self.

```
List<Location> listLocation = new ArrayList<Location>();
```

When location updated. I were store Location to listLocation,remove the old marker . Then add the newest location to Gmap.

```
     @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            countUpdatePos++;

        listLocation.add(location);
        LatLng lastLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                location.getLongitude());
        gmap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(lastLocation, 16));
        String cityName = null;
        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try {
            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),
                    location.getLongitude(), 1);
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                int a = addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex();
                for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        cityName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i);
                    } else {
                        cityName = cityName + ", "
                                + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (countUpdatePos == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.updated_position), 2000)
                    .show();
            progressToLoadMap.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            checkStartActivity = true;
            timer = new MyCount((int) totalTime * 60 * 1000, 1000);
            timer.start();
        }

        if (listLocation.size() > 1) {
            listLocation.add(location);
//          gmap.clear();
            LatLng newLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                    location.getLongitude());
            gmap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(newLocation, 16));

            myMarker = gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
                    listLocation.get(listLocation.size() - 1).getLatitude(),
                    listLocation.get(listLocation.size() - 1).getLongitude())));
            if (myMarker != null) {
                myMarker.remove();
                myMarker = null;
            }
            gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(getResources().getString(
                            R.string.current_location_found)).snippet(cityName)
                    .position(newLocation));
            if (listLocation.get(listLocation.size() - 1) != null
                    && listLocation.get(listLocation.size() - 1) != null) {
                gmap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                        .add(new LatLng(listLocation.get(
                                listLocation.size() - 1).getLatitude(),
                                listLocation.get(listLocation.size() - 1)
                                        .getLongitude()),
                                new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location
                                        .getLongitude())).width(3)
                        .color(Color.BLUE));
            }
```

But when run activity, all marker still display, and no polyline add to gmap :(. Help me
 here is picture
[image]

Comment: so you want to remove items from arrylist?

Comment: yes. I want to remove previous marker on arraylist

Comment: First check that if your arraylist contains data and if it is then check `if(marker!=null){ marker.remove();`. when you add new marker.

Comment: so u know where r u updating ur list right? use arrylist.clear() there and then add na

Comment: yes I checked. But it seem  this is still not working. arraylist.clear() can not solve problem. Because my process is :
  I add Location to arraylist.
  I remove Marker by arr.get(arr.size -1)
  I add Marker by arr.get(arr.size)
 Sory DIVA i know wrong your word.

Answer (score 5):

I hade the same problem and after checking my code I found that I am calling the method that add the marker twice in the oncreate and onresume events so 2 markers are added at the same position on the map so when I remove the marker using marker.remove() method one is removed but the other one remain so I thought it is not deleted. I removed the method call from the oncreate event and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is correct but Just need little bit modification for Marker:
Set this globally:

```
Marker myMarker;
```

**In you onCreate()**

```
myMarker = gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(listLocation.get(
                            listLocation.size() - 1).getLatitude(),
                            listLocation.get(listLocation.size() - 1)
                                    .getLongitude())));
```

Then Whenver you want to add another **Marker** then Just check it out if Is there already any other marker is present. If yes then remove it if you want.

For that:

```
if(myMarker!=null)
{
  marker.remove();
  marker = null;
}

myMarker  = gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title(getResources().getString(
                        R.string.current_location_found)).snippet(cityName)
                .position(newLocation));
```

For Polyline you might check if lat,long are not null.

Comment: thanks you. But it still not working. I update my code snippet that display Marker. Please help me.

Comment: hey, why do you put the myMarker = gmap.addMarker(...) in OnCreate()?I think if it is, then myMarker is only call once

Comment: You can put that code wherever you want.forget about oncreate().Now tell me you want to show gmap with one/two marker?

Comment: I want to show gmap with one lastest marker after location update

Answer (score 0):

I've seen something like this before.

try making

```
//put this at the top of your class
Marker myMarker;



//this is using the reference
myMarker = gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title(getResources().getString(
                    R.string.current_location_found)).snippet(cityName)
            .position(newLocation));
myMarker.remove();
```

an instance variable. WHen you call remove() it needs to be the same marker that you added.

make sure you keep a reference to the marker :

```
        myMarker = gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title(getResources().getString(
                        R.string.current_location_found)).snippet(cityName)
                .position(newLocation));
        if (listLocation.get(listLocation.size() - 1) != null
                && listLocation.get(listLocation.size() - 1) != null) {
            gmap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                    .add(new LatLng(listLocation.get(
                            listLocation.size() - 1).getLatitude(),
                            listLocation.get(listLocation.size() - 1)
                                    .getLongitude()),
                            new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location
                                    .getLongitude())).width(3)
                    .color(Color.BLUE));
```

Comment: gMap.clear() doesn't clear out all the markers either?  A way you can do this is something like keeping track of ALL markers you add to the map by storing them in a list. List<Marker> markerList = new ArrayList<Marker>();.. every time you add a marker, add it to the map, and when you want to remove it grab that item from the list and call marker.remove() and it should remove it from the map. Or clear() if you want to clear all of them.